# Apache httpPost upload speed

Tags: java, performance, upload

writing code to upload files to file host, but speed are extremely slow,i'm using newest jar's. Uploading speed are like 10 times slower then using browser. What could cause this problem?

```
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(xxxx);

        CustomMultiPartEntity multipartContent = new CustomMultiPartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE, new CustomMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {

            @Override
            public void transferred(long num) {
                item.setProgress((int)num / 1024);
            }
        });

        ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(item.getFile());

        multipartContent.addPart("uploads[]", cbFile);

        httppost.setEntity(multipartContent);

        HttpResponse response = clientManager.getClient().execute(httppost, localContext);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String htmlResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

My client code here:

```
private DefaultHttpClient client;
```

private final HttpParams params = new SyncBasicHttpParams();

```
public ClientManager()
{
    ClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager();
    ((ThreadSafeClientConnManager) connectionManager).setDefaultMaxPerRoute(30);
    ((ThreadSafeClientConnManager) connectionManager).setMaxTotal(1000);

    CookieSpecFactory csf = new CookieSpecFactory()
    {
        @Override
        public CookieSpec newInstance(final HttpParams params)
        {
            return new BrowserCompatSpec()
            {
                @Override
                public void validate(final Cookie cookie, final CookieOrigin origin) throws MalformedCookieException
                {
                }
            };
        }
    };

    HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(params, false);
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 40 * 1000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 40 * 3000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(params, true);

    //HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize(params, 10485760);

    params.setParameter(CookieSpecPNames.SINGLE_COOKIE_HEADER, true);
    params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/10.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0");
    params.setParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS, true);
    params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);

    client = new ContentEncodingHttpClient(connectionManager, params);

    client.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(new HttpClientRequestRetryHandler());
    client.getCookieSpecs().register("EASY", csf);
    params.setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, "EASY");
}
```

}

Comment: Please don't get downvoted by posting one liners of your problem

Comment: *"What could cause this problem?"* - Without seeing your code, we can only guess.